# Open and close Dialog using Props on ReactJS? My modal keeps open and don't close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I created a Dialog component that gets props from other component

```
        function ConfimationDialog(props)   {
            return (
                <Dialog           
                PaperProps={{style: {backgroundColor: props.colorBackground}}}
                open={props.modalName}
                onClose={props.cancelAction}
                >
                    <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{props.textTitle}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent >
                        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                        {props.textDetail}
                        </DialogContentText>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>            
                        <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.confirmAction} color={props.buttonColor} >
                        {props.textConfirm}
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.cancelAction}  >
                        {props.textCancel}
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            )
        }
```

The component that calls the dialog:

```
        <ConfirmationDialog
            modalName=          'modalSaida'
            backgroundColor=    'primary'
            buttonColor=        'secondary'
            cancelAction=       {handleCancelar}
            confirmAction=      {handleConfirmar}

            textTitle=          'Você deseja remover os clientes que foram marcado?'
            textDetail=         'Você não poderá voltar atrás.'
            textConfirm=        'Confirmar'
            textCancel=         'Cancelar'
        />
```

The actions:

```
        const [modalSaida, setModalSaida] = React.useState(false);

        function handleCancelar()    {  
            setModalSaida(false);
        }    

        function handleConfirmar()    {  
            setModalSaida(false);
            dispatch(Actions.deleteClientes(props.idSelected));   
        }
```

But **I just managed to make confirmAction work**. The action that closes the modal simply doesn't work, making my modal open even when I start the app.

That cancelAction prop are getting in the Dialog component but the function is not being called

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is you set the Dialog open property to the name when I think it's used  as a boolean to determine if the dialog is open.

Source: https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dillan Wilding, that's the solution:

To work I just changed this:

> modalName=           'modalSaida'

To this:

> modalName=           {modalSaida}

In here:

```
        <ConfirmationDialog
            modalName=          {modalSaida}
            backgroundColor=    'primary'
            buttonColor=        'secondary'
            cancelAction=       {handleCancelar}
            confirmAction=      {handleConfirmar}               
            textTitle=          'Você deseja remover os clientes que foram marcados?'
            textDetail=         'Você não poderá voltar atrás.'
            textConfirm=        'Confirmar'
            textCancel=         'Cancelar'
        />
```